# Bootstrap Multiple select dropdown not working while appending

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown, multiple-select

I am appending html of one which contain multiple select dropdown to another another div on button click; but after appending div multiple select dropdown not working. Here is my code [Example](https://fiddle.jshell.net/0tpLod7h/)

Please help me with this. Thanks

Comment: Check my answer which also allow you to **Select All option** from the clone dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a soluition for you ***in your own fiddle***.

The issue was simple - The thing is that when we append a code we have to ***`destroy` any  `plugin` which is used inside it and `re-init` it again***.

Because append only **copies the HTML code and repaste it**, it will never there in the dome when the plugin was called into the page, so the plugin will not work with the appended element. For that we have to recall the plugin.

Hope it's helpful for your *cheers*.

Here is the link for the answere ***[jsfiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/jithinrajpr7/172zpqvq/1/)***

Answer (score 2):

Please find below mentioned solution.

In html you need to create template like describe below.

```
<div id="template" class="hidden">
    <div class="form-group" id="multiselect">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="rolename">Role Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <select id="dates-field2" class="multiselect-ui form-control" multiple="multiple">
                <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
                <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
                <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
                <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
                <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
                <option value="onions">Onions</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is your jQuery code.

```
var html = $('#template').html();

$('.multiselect-ui').multiselect({
    includeSelectAllOption: true
});

$('#append-btn').click(function() {
    $(html).appendTo('.div2');
    $('.multiselect-ui').multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: true
    });
});
```

You can find working fiddle here : https://fiddle.jshell.net/wuyy56gs/1/

Let me know if it not works.

Answer (score 1):

Save the html before you call multiselect, rebuild the multiselect when you append it

```
var html = $('#multiselect').html();

 $('.multiselect-ui').multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: true
    });

    $('#append-btn').click(function(){

     $(html).appendTo('.div2');
    $('.multiselect-ui').multiselect('rebuild')
    })
```

demo:https://fiddle.jshell.net/wuyy56gs/

Comment: Thanks @madalin ivascu. But I don't understand in my web page dropdown appending two time please see image http://imgur.com/xBeRD1Q. Can you please help me

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with the solution https://fiddle.jshell.net/0tpLod7h/1/

```js
var cnt = 2;
var html = $('#multiselect').html();
 $('.multiselect-ui').multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: true
    });
    
    $('#append-btn').click(function(){
     cnt++;
      $(html).appendTo('.div2');
     $('.div2 > div').last().find('select').attr('id', 'dates-field' + cnt);
      $('#dates-field' + cnt).multiselect('rebuild');
    })
```

```css
span.multiselect-native-select {
 position: relative
}
span.multiselect-native-select select {
 border: 0!important;
 clip: rect(0 0 0 0)!important;
 height: 1px!important;
 margin: -1px -1px -1px -3px!important;
 overflow: hidden!important;
 padding: 0!important;
 position: absolute!important;
 width: 1px!important;
 left: 50%;
 top: 30px
}
.multiselect-container {
 position: absolute;
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0
}
.multiselect-container .input-group {
 margin: 5px
}
.multiselect-container>li {
 padding: 0
}
.multiselect-container>li>a.multiselect-all label {
 font-weight: 700
}
.multiselect-container>li.multiselect-group label {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 3px 20px 3px 20px;
 height: 100%;
 font-weight: 700
}
.multiselect-container>li.multiselect-group-clickable label {
 cursor: pointer
}
.multiselect-container>li>a {
 padding: 0
}
.multiselect-container>li>a>label {
 margin: 0;
 height: 100%;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-weight: 400;
 padding: 3px 0 3px 30px
}
.multiselect-container>li>a>label.radio, .multiselect-container>li>a>label.checkbox {
 margin: 0
}
.multiselect-container>li>a>label>input[type=checkbox] {
 margin-bottom: 5px
}
.btn-group>.btn-group:nth-child(2)>.multiselect.btn {
 border-top-left-radius: 4px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 4px
}
.form-inline .multiselect-container label.checkbox, .form-inline .multiselect-container label.radio {
 padding: 3px 20px 3px 40px
}
.form-inline .multiselect-container li a label.checkbox input[type=checkbox], .form-inline .multiselect-container li a label.radio input[type=radio] {
 margin-left: -20px;
 margin-right: 0
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group" id="multiselect">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="rolename">Role Name</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select id="dates-field2" class="multiselect-ui form-control" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
            <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
            <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
            <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
            <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
            <option value="onions">Onions</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="div2">

</div>

<button id="append-btn">Append
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can append direct html code of your current code.
This example also allow you to **Select All** option from the clone dropdown.
For example :

```
<script>
var i = 0; 
$('#append-btn').click(function(){
     var html = '';
     html += '<div class="form-group" id="multiselect">';
     html += '<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="rolename">Role Name</label>';
     html += '<div class="col-md-4 test">';
     html += '    <select id="dates-field2" class="multiselect-ui'+i+' form-control" multiple="multiple">';
     html += '        <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>';
     html += '        <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>';
     html += '        <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>';
     html += '        <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>';
     html += '        <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>';
     html += '        <option value="onions">Onions</option>';
     html += '    </select>';
     html += '</div>';
     html += '</div>';
     $(html).appendTo('.div2');
     $('.multiselect-ui'+i).multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: true
     });
     i++
 });
</script>
```

Here is working example :
https://fiddle.jshell.net/0tpLod7h/2/